# AWS: One way trust to be established dynamically between cross AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-iam

Need to implement a scenario where we need to establish the trust relationship between 2 different AWS accounts dynamically.

Let's suppose there is AWS Account 1 (on client's side) and AWS Account 2 (created by customer using automation scripts, as and when needed). So, this 1 way trust relationship needs to be established dynamically (or rather automatically) every-time when customer creates Account 2 (as and when needed).

Let me know, if you have any suggestions to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I am understanding the question correctly as long as account 1 is not changing. You should be able to create a role in account '2' which allows account a role in account 1 to assume it and this could then be given the appropriate privileges. This role could be created automatically each time